# What makes an electrical device draws a current

Tags: current

May be this is very silly question but i want to ask that if the system has 220v and we connect our mobile charger with this draws very little current and when we connect iron with this very same socket draws much higher amount of current.

My question is that what make current flow through device and what mentioned the quantity?

Comment: Its impedance. You can imagine load as being in parallel to voltage source thus the voltage across it is constant and expanding Ohms law to contain impedance (instead of resistance): I=U/Z, in complex ofcourse.

Comment: I think a tap, pipes and water bucket analogy is good here.

Answer (score 2):

Current will flow when the circuit is closed. If you have an open circuit it acts as infinite impedance, thus no current will flow. But as soon as you close the circuit (connect terminals of a voltage source) current will flow. 
Let's say you complete the circuit with copper wire (aka short circuit), this is essentially no impedance and the current will shoot to infinity. Now of course, in reality voltage sources have current limiters and will not allow the current to shoot to infinity. 
So open circuit equals infinity impedance (no current flow) and short circuit equals zero impedance (infinite current flow). 
As you decrease the impedance, the current drawn from the source increases and vice versa.
Good luck!

Comment: A copper wire has a resistance, so even if you connected it across an infinite bus bar, you wouldn't have infinite current flowing, just a very large amount (until the wire melts of course!). An open circuit acts as a very large impedance, but unless the terminals are an infinite distance apart, there will be a finite resistance - for example air has a resistance of anywhere from 1e9 to 1e16 ohms/m. Very large, yes, but not infinite.

Comment: I understand why you say that, but when I say infinite and no resistance, they are relative terms. The words are only a means of making a point, I could have said very very very large and very very very small. The objective of my answer was to suggest that as you decrease the impedance the current increases.

Comment: the hydraulic analogy can help: if you connect a reservoir/dam to a lower lying area through a tube, depending on the diameter of the tube more or less water will flow. If there is no tube, no water is drawn.

Answer (score 1):

When you connect a device , such as a charger or an electric iron, to a voltage source you complete an electrical circuit that will allow electrical charge to flow (i.e. current).

[image]

The amount of current in the circuit will be determined by the resistance or impedance of the device. The higher the resistance or impedance the smaller the current.

The term **impedance** relates to a load that has component(s) (capacitor,inductor,resistor) that alters the phase angle between the voltage and current in the circuit

The relationship between voltage, current and resistance (impedance) can be expressed using Ohm's law  V = IxR or U = IxZ

The lower the resistance or impedance the more current will be drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Voltage is a difference in potential, like pressure, or height.

When electric charges like electrons and protons are subject to a voltage, they experience an electromotive force. Like the air in a balloon wants to get out, or a boulder wants to roll downhill due to the force of gravity.

Just because the electric charges are subject to a force does not mean they move. How much they are able to move depends on the *impedance* preventing them from doing so.

A rough analogy: your water pressure is approximately constant, as is the voltage of an electrical outlet or a battery. Open the hose a little, and a little water comes out. Open the hose a lot, and a lot of water comes out.

This is where the analogy breaks down, because electric circuits don't spew charge everywhere like an open hose does: it all stays in the circuit and flows in a loop.